# Positive semi-definiteness of a complex Matrix with special form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A,B,C$ complex $n\times n$  Matrices with ones on the diagonal and entries of absolute value 1. Further, let $$A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n,\; B=(b_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n \mbox{ and } C=(a_{ij}b_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n.$$

**Can we say something about the positive semi-definiteness of $A$ if we know that $B$ and $C$ have this property?**

Any hint to a similar problem or result or counter-example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are $A$, $B$, and $C$ related somehow? Why should positive semi-definiteness of $A$ depend at all on $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @User8128 Thank you. I forgot something ... edited the question

Comment: Got it. Thanks makes more sense!

Comment: Not sure about the star notation. Is $C$ equal to the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @PaulAljabar Yes.. its just a componentwise product.

Comment: Okay, maybe the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *complex matrices* you mean Hermitian matrices the answer is yes, for a silly reason and a non-silly reason. Suppose $B$ and $C$ are PSD with $1$s on the diagonal and all off diagonal entries of absolute value $1$.  You ask if the elementwise quotient $A=(c_{i,j}/b_{i,j})$ is PSD.
The silly reason is that the complex conjugate of a complex number of absolute value $1$ is its reciprocal.  So the matrix $D=(\bar{b}_{i,j})$ is the matrix of reciprocals of the entries in $B$, and $A$ is the element-wise product of the two PSD matrices $A$ and $D$.  Which it is also PSD, by the non-silly   *Schur product theorem*:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem.

Comment: Thank you! However, by complex matrix I mean a matrix with complex entries-no further regularity assumed.

Comment: I mean, what is a *complex positive definite* matrix for you?  Do you require $\bar z' M z\ge 0$ for all complex vectors $z$, with $\bar z'$ denoting the conjugate transpose?  If so, the argument I supplied answers your question in the affirmative.

Comment: Yes, its just that you wrote that the answer is yes for hermitian matrices. But,if $B$ is psd and not hermitian then also its transpose conjugate $D$ will be psd. However then you dont have $B=D$ and hence $C\circ D\neq A$ ($\circ$ denotes hadamard) since $c_{i,j}*b^{-1}_{j,i}\neq a_{i,j}$.

Comment: Can you tell me precisely what you mean by *PSD*, and supply an example of a non-Hermitian PSD matrix?  The [Wikipedia article]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)  does not help me understand more clearly  what you are thinking about.

Comment: You are right. Psd implies hermitian.